# Flask SQLAlchemy : IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush) in a for loop

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to add tracks to playlists in a for loop, like so:

```
data = zip(playlists, artists, tracks, uris)

count=0
for d in data:
    # check if playlist is new to database
    if db.session.query(Playlist).filter_by(title=d[0]).count() < 1:
        # ADD FIRST TRACK
        track = Track(title=d[2],
                      artist=d[1],
                      uri=d[3],
                      track_id=1)

        db.session.add(track)

        playlist = Playlist(title=d[0], 
                            user=User.query.get(1))

        playlist.tracks.append(track)
        db.session.add(playlist)

    else:               
        # ADD TRACKS
        track = Track(title=d[2],
                      artist=d[1],
                      uri=d[3],
                      track_id=count+1)

        db.session.add(track)

        # look for existent playlist
        pl = Playlist.query.filter_by(title=d[0]).first()

        print ('EXISTENT PLAYLIST', pl)

        # add tracks to existent playlist
        pl.tracks.append(track)

    count+=1
    db.session.commit()
```

These are my models:

```
class Playlist(db.Model):
    """
    Model for storing playlist information belonging to a specific user
    """
    __tablename__ = 'playlist'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    user = db.relationship('User',
                backref=db.backref('playlists', lazy='dynamic'))

    tracks = db.relationship('Track', secondary=tracks,
            backref=db.backref('playlists', lazy='dynamic'))


    def __init__(self, title, user):
        self.title = title
        self.user = user


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Playlist %r>' % (self.title)


    @property
    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
       return {
           'id' : self.id,
           'title': self.title,
           'user': self.user.serialize,
           'tracks': [ item.serialize for item in self.tracks]
       }



class Track(db.Model):
    """
    Model for storing track information
    """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(140))
    artist = db.Column(db.String(140))
    uri = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    track_id = db.Column(db.String(140), unique=True)


    def __init__(self, title, artist, uri, track_id):
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
        self.uri = uri
        self.track_id = track_id


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Track %r>, <Artist %r>' % (self.title, self.artist)


    @property
    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
       return {
           'id' : self.id,
           'title': self.title,
           'artist': self.artist,
           'uri': self.uri,
           'track_id': self.track_id
       }
```

Everything works and all tracks are created and added up to the first playlist, but as soon as I move to the second playlist, I get the following traceback:

> IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: track.track_id [SQL: u'INSERT INTO track (title, artist, uri, track_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('No Intention', 'Dirty Projectors', 'spotify:track:4Ozug40zUcMiE2s1neJQRb', 1)]

Full traceback:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 17:43:29] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/Documents/Code/Apps/myapp/app.py", line 459, in do_admin_login
    if db.session.query(Playlist).filter_by(title=d[0]).count() < 1:
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3089, in count
    return self.from_self(col).scalar()
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2843, in scalar
    ret = self.one()
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2814, in one
    ret = self.one_or_none()
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2784, in one_or_none
    ret = list(self)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2854, in __iter__
    self.session._autoflush()
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1407, in _autoflush
    util.raise_from_cause(e)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1397, in _autoflush
    self.flush()
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2171, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2291, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2255, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 389, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 548, in execute
    uow
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 181, in save_obj
    mapper, table, insert)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 835, in _emit_insert_statements
    execute(statement, params)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/Users/vitorpatalano/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
**IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: track.track_id [SQL: u'INSERT INTO track (title, artist, uri, track_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('No Intention', 'Dirty Projectors', 'spotify:track:4Ozug40zUcMiE2s1neJQRb', 1)]**
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 17:43:29] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 17:43:29] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 17:43:29] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 17:43:29] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 17:43:29] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to know from your code what the data you are trying to insert looks like but from reading your models definition and the error, you are violating a unique constraint in your Track table. Your Track `uri` attribute and `track_id` attribute have a unique constraint which means you can only have one unique track `uri` and one `track_id` in the whole database. Could it be possible that a user might have the same track in two different playlists? if this is possible than you should remove the unique constraint in your Track table definition on `track_id` and `uri` and see if this error will disappear.